# The O'l Vegas Pink and Green

Tags: windows-7, display, sony-vegas

I've just got my new HDPVR 2 Gaming capture device and it records well it's just as soon as I get it onto Vegas I get some pink screen. It works for about 5 second in then it's all pink and green, I've heard something about resolution, but you can't change the resolution in HDPVR (that I know of ...)

With my old ROXIO recorder I got stuff into vegas with AVI but all HDPVR does is MP4 and it could also be my computer ... it's not how we would say "up for the job" anymore.

So if anyone has an idea what's wrong it would be great if you could help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see red numbers in the frames? Or is the whole screen pink? Usually, pink means that your video and audio are out of sync and need to be re-aligned.

Comment: Oh really? That's a new one to me, how would I go about re-aligning them? I get the whole pink screen http://screencast.com/t/rw4Z2aUHi

Comment: It could be that you're in full screen preview. Go to the view tab. Then find and click on Video Preview. Or press ALT + 4.